# How to start rviz with a fixed frame

Tags: rviz, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have come across this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/195962/rviz-fixed-frame-world-does-not-exist/) using the   static_transform_publisher from the bash, but this is inconvinient.
The arguments seem to offer this but cannot find an example what args `-f` acutally takes

```
  pc~/catkin_ws$ rviz -h
[ INFO] [1461508601.744858346]: rviz version 1.11.8
[ INFO] [1461508601.744970393]: compiled against OGRE version 1.8.1 (Byatis)
rviz command line options:
  -h [ --help ]               Produce this help message
  -s [ --splash-screen ] arg  A custom splash-screen image to display
  --help-file arg             A custom html file to show as the help screen
  -d [ --display-config ] arg A display config file (.rviz) to load
  -f [ --fixed-frame ] arg    Set the fixed frame
```

Could someone post an example for example this frame (no trans, no rot)

```
rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 map my_frame 10
```

**EDIT**
So what I do is using a launch file to pack both commands together:

```
<launch>
<!-- set up the cosys -->
 <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map2frame_0" 
    args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0 0 0 1 map frame_0 100" />
<!-- start rviz -->
  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="my_rviz" 
    args="-d $(find rviz_markers)/include/rviz_config.rviz"/>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232731/how-to-start-rviz-with-a-fixed-frame/) by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on ROS Answers with karma: 748 on 2016-04-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You would run RViz like this: `rosrun rviz rviz -f my_frame`

This will set the Fixed Frame to `my_frame` under Global Options. You can also do that from the GUI btw.

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on 2016-04-24**:
what a pitty, so i cant get around publishing the `my_frame`.  Do you know how to specify a path when using a launch file for the config, eg:

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-04-24**:
If `my_frame` already exists, then you don't need the static transform publisher anymore. By setting the fixed frame to `my_frame`, RViz will visualize everything relative to `my_frame` instead of `map`, which is the default fixed frame.